# Ansi Encoding for Embedded Fonts in PDF Output

Tags: pdf, luatex, fontspec, font-encodings

Rendering PDFs with identical fonts using InDesign versus using LuaLaTeX with fontspec in TeXworks, I have found differences in Acrobat Reader's descriptions of the embedded font types and encoding.

.otf fonts from InDesign tend to read as Type 1 and .ttfs as TrueType, and both are ANSI encoded:
[image: PDF from InDesign]

Whereas fonts from LuaLaTeX possess the (CID) qualifier after their Type and are Identity-H encoded:
[image: PDF from LuaLaTeX]

How can I make LuaLaTeX produce a PDF with ANSI Encoding for all embedded fonts?

Comment: [XY](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2449/5763) - why do you want to do this?

Comment: Some publications won't accept Identity-H, claiming it leads to printing errors. Is there a package or any other way to change encoding from LuaLaTeX? (fontenc is buggy with LuaLaTeX and fontspec and does not seem to offer Ansi/Identity-H options anyway)

Comment: Not to my knowledge. These publications should fix their software; Identity-H is perfectly fine.

Comment: I have problems importing pdfs into Inkscape when the Identity-H encoding is used. It would be nice to somehow change the encoding to something more standard.